# Browser block float logic of different heights

Tags: css, css-float

What is the browsers logic to position elements like this:

[image]

Basically, as I understand this can be recreated without bootstrap with a simple container block and and `width: 33.333333%` blocks of different heights. Why is the `d` block not floating to the left, under `a` block?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8qbuczau/

Comment: because you have not cleared the float on d and b block is higher than c block.  It's easier to use flex for this now

Comment: @Pete I know of solutions to this, easiest of them for bootstrap users is to use bootrap 4, which uses flex. This is a thetorical question,trying to understand the logic behind floating in browsers.

Comment: That's the first part of my comment and flex is not bootstrap - you don't need a whole library just to achieve a column  layout

Comment: @data you want e and f in same line with d?

Answer (score 1):

You would expect that the `d` block would sit on the new line with the `e` and `f` block but the reason it does not is because there is enough **horizontal** and **vertical** space on the first row for it to sit underneath the `c` block.

If you take away the line breaks from the `b` element then `d` will be forced to the next line as there is no more vertical space for it to fill.

```css
.row {
  overflow: auto;
}

div
{
  border: 1px dashed maroon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.col-md-4
{
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 33.333333%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">a</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      b
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">c</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">d</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">e</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you add more line breaks to the `b` element you will see that e and f also have the same behaviour.

[Per the w3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-floats-3/#propdef-float):

> If the float reference is not a line box, the element generates a box
>   that is floated to the block-start and line-start outer edges of the
>   float reference.

Also:

> If the float reference is not a line box, the element generates a box
>   that is floated to the block-end and line-start outer edges of the
>   float reference.

With floats, they will naturally try to move to the start or end of their `containing` element going line by line if there is enough space. What stops this from happening is that usually there is not enough space for them to sit on the end of the previous line so they reposition themselves at the beginning of the next line

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `d` become new row why dont you split it into 2 different `<div class="row">`

Total col in 1 row should be max 12. Never try if you make it become more than 12, may be thats what make the positioning become messy.